# mock JSON response in Backbone Fetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js, model

I'm learning Backbone and want to "mock" the results of a `.fetch()` call within a model. I do not want to use a testing library or actually hit an external service.

Basically I have a setting in my model, where if `this.options.mock === true`, then just use an internal JSON object as the "result" of the fetch. Else, actually hit the API with a real AJAX request.

However, this doesn't seem to work. My view successfully renders with the model data when I hit the actual API ("real" fetch), but not whenever I try and pass in fake data.

Is there a way to fake a Fetch response in Backbone, without bringing in a testing library like Sinon?

here is the complete model (at least the relevant portions of it). Basically, the model fetches data, and formats it for a template. and then the view which owns the model renders it out.

```
'use strict';
(function (app, $, Backbone) {

    app.Models.contentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        /**
         * Initializes model. Fetches data from API.
         * @param  {Object} options Configuration settings.
         */
        initialize: function (options) {
            var that = this;
            that.set({
                'template': options.template,
                'mock': options.mock || false
            });

            $.when(this.retrieveData()).then(function (data) {
                that.formatDataForTemplate(data);
            }, function () {
                console.error('failed!');
            });
        },

        retrieveData: function () {

            var that = this, deferred = $.Deferred();

            if (typeof fbs_settings !== 'undefined' && fbs_settings.preview === 'true') {
                deferred.resolve(fbs_settings.data);
            }
            else if (that.get('mock')) {
                console.info('in mock block');

                var mock = {
                  'title': 'Test Title',
                  'description': 'test description',
                  'position': 1,
                  'byline': 'Author'
                };

                deferred.resolve(mock);
            }
            else {
                // hit API like normal.
                console.info('in ajax block');
                that.fetch({
                    success: function (collection, response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response.promotedContent.contentPositions[0]);
                    },
                    error: function(collection, response) {
                        console.error('error: fetch failed for contentModel.');
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise();
        },

        /**
         * Formats data on a per-template basis.
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        formatDataForTemplate: function (data) {
            if (this.get('template') === 'welcomead_default') {
                this.set({
                    'title': data.title,
                    'description': data.description,
                    'byline': data.author
                });

            }
            // trigger the data formatted event for the view to render.
            this.trigger('dataFormatted');
        }
    });
})(window.app, window.jQuery, window.Backbone);
```

Relevant bit from the view (ContentView):

```
this.model = new app.Models.contentModel({template: this.templateName});
this.listenTo(this.model, 'dataFormatted', this.render);
```

Is the data being set so fast that the listener hasn't been set up yet?

Comment: Could you include a little more of the code surrounding your if-else block? Where in the model is it and how is it being called? Remember the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From the code you posted it's pretty hard for anyone else to spot what's wrong.

Comment: `fetch()` triggers series of dependent events which you cannot result by such way. You have to override [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

Comment: @ivarni I've added my complete model to the original post.

Comment: Also, this model is for read-only data. It will never save/update to the server. It's simply a way for me to encapsulate an AJAX call and the response data into a single area of my app for readability sake.

Comment: Yeah.. that's pretty different from the original bit of code :) I assume you see the `in mock block` printed in console? To me the code looks fine, but I don't have much experience using the jQuery promise API. Also, in [this](https://jsbin.com/bujileheyi/edit?html,js,console) slightly modified jsbin of your code it seems to work just fine. You're basically triggering an event while in initialize since you shortcutted the code so most likely the view haven't set up its listener for that event yet. Try adding a timeout before resolving the deferred in the mock case.

Comment: @ivarni - I've added the relevant code from the view to the OP -- now that you mention it, I suspect the view listener isn't having time to setup by the time the model data is set when using local.. Hm! What would be a way around that? And yes, I am seeing `in mock block` printed in the console so I know it's executing.

Comment: @Prefix I probably edited while you typed. Use `setTimeout`.

Comment: @ivarni aha! that was it!! Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes :-) thank you!

Comment: @Prefix No worries. It's not the easiest thing to spot. I expected some esoteric jQuery-error when I made the jsbin and when I actually saw it working there I had to stop and think a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here isn't with the actual implementation of `retrieveData` but with the way it's being called. When you resolve the deferred before returning you're basically making it instant. This leads to `formatDataForTemplate` being called while your model is still initializing.

So when you do

```
this.model = new app.Models.contentModel({template: this.templateName});
this.listenTo(this.model, 'dataFormatted', this.render);
```

The `dataFormatted` event ends up being triggered before the listener has registered.

One solution is to use a timeout which should work with just

```
setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve(mock);
});
```

as that will delay the resolve untill the next round of the event loop when the listener is in place.

Another solution, not involving the `setTimeout` would be to not call `retrieveData` during model initialization but rather let the view do it after it has attached its listeners.

```
this.model = new app.Models.contentModel({template: this.templateName});
this.listenTo(this.model, 'dataFormatted', this.render);
this.model.retrieveData();
```

I would prefer the latter but if this is just about mocking data to work offline it doesn't really matter in my opinion.

Unrelated to that it's worth noting that the actual [signature](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) for initialize on a model is `new Model([attributes], [options])` so your initialize should probably look like this

```
initialize: function (attributes, options) {
    var that = this;
    that.set({
        'template': options.template,
        'mock': options.mock || false
    });
```

Just for the sake of readability. That again means that since you are passing only one object you should not need to call `set` at all.

Comment: Great tips all around. I've restructured my code to avoid the setTimeout by breaking the call to retrieveData out of initialize. Also was not aware of the `Model([attributes])` capability so I've changed to that as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Prefix Happy to help. Generally you don't want to do anything that can potentially touch the DOM in you initialize functions. This goes for views, models and collections alike.

Comment: I see! Should all dom manipulation be contained to the render method? What kind of things should I be doing inside `initialize()` in, say, a view? Thanks again.

Comment: @Prefix I prefer to do as little as possible in my `initialize` and most of all I try to avoid doing things that has side-effects outside my class. Most of the time I'm just setting up event-listeners or saving values passed to me in `options`.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the fetch function like this.

```js
var MockedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attr, options) {
    if (options.mock) {
      this.fetch = this.fakeFetch;
    }
  },
  url: 'http://someUrlThatWIllNeverBeCalled.com',
  fakeFetch: function(options) {
    var self = this
    this.set({
      'title': 'Test Title',
      'description': 'test description',
      'position': 1,
      'byline': 'Author'
    });

    if (typeof options.success === 'function') {
      options.success(self, {}, {})
    }
  }
});
var mockedModel = new MockedModel(null, {
  mock: true
})
mockedModel.fetch({
  success: function(model, xhr) {
    alert(model.get('title'));
  }
});
```

```html
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```